# how to pass domain,port number,username and password from user input to worklight http adapter

Tags: adapter, ibm-mobilefirst

read values from user input

```
XML:
  `<protocol>http</protocol>
  <domain>192.168.1.10</domain>  
  <port>9080</port>
  <username>user</username>
   <password>pwd</password>`
```

ok....i will explain briefly........

1. i am trying to access from process servers running in different
   pcs.....
2. if i specify details like above  it will become specific to one
   system only...

So i want to pass details from my app to which i want to connect

Comment: This is not doable. You declare all of this data in yourAdapter.xml beforehand.

Comment: is there any possibility connect server dynamically?

Comment: Do you mean: is it possible for an application to dynamically connect to a worklight server? No. The server URL an application connects to is set in application-descriptor.xml, and is set during build time and cannot be changed during runtime.

Comment: thank you idan for prompt reply.......i want to connect some remote server from worklight adapter for eg: process server with domain: 192.168.1.20 and port:9080 along with user name and password

Comment: In your adapter's XML, there is a <connectivity> section, there you define to where the adapter will try to connec. You cannot set these dynamically.

Comment: But you CAN use variables from worklight.properties

Comment: how to inject values into xml from worklight properties

Comment: I think that in order to provide you a GOOD answer, we need you to provide the actual use case, what it is that you're trying to achieve. Please edit your question with an example.

Comment: ok....i will explain briefly........                                  1)i am trying to connect access data from tomcat server

Comment: @naresh, if your question is answered, please mark it as Answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the additions to the question, the answer is still - it is not possible. You cannot dynamically set the connectivity settings of an adapter from the application (or from the server) during runtime.

You didn't explain what is the need to connect to these different data sources, so I will give two options of different scenarios:

1. Use two adapters with different procedures and on the client-side add some logic that will call the right procedure whenever required.
2. Perhaps this training module will help you: [Advanced adapter usage and mashup](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/04_07_Advanced_adapter_usage_and_mashup.pdf), if this is your scenario. Read through it.