# Worklight Adapter override adapter xml

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

Worklight 6.1

Once an adapter is deployed is it possible programmatically from within an adapters procedure to override the   and  that was previously defined in the adapters xml?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all Worklight releases up to and including the recently released IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation 6.3 (formerly Worklight), once a JavaScript or Java adapter has been deployed it becomes an object that is stored in memory. It is therefore not possible to alter the backend URL properties that were defined in the adapter's XML file.

Related questions:

- [IBM Worklight - Can I change invokeProcedure hostname and port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17543436/ibm-worklight-can-i-change-invokeprocedure-hostname-and-port)
- [5.0.6 - Changing Adapter domain and port configuration after deploy through configuration - for QA and Testing team in development process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17491703/5-0-6-changing-adapter-domain-and-port-configuration-after-deploy-through-conf)
- [IBM Worklight - How to change dynamically domain/hostname to which the adapter connects from the client at launch or runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25158948/ibm-worklight-how-to-change-dynamically-domain-hostname-to-which-the-adapter-c)

Comment: Thank You ..  Appreciate the related links.