# Where does the adapter files go after deploying them to worklight server?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server

I have general question:
The WL adapter contains two files (xml and js), when we build the adapter, these two files are zipped into (***.adapter) which we use to deploy the adapter to WL server.
During the deployment, the server compile the (****.adapter) file, and if it is successful, it gives a successful deployment message.

My question: 
After doing the deployment, where are the compiling files go that the server generated during the deployment?
what is the directory that they are placed into after the deployment?
We have searched all the file system and couldn't find them.

We are using Enterprise edition server in our company.
WL version 6.2.0.1.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this answer: [Worklight Adapter override adapter xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27388508/worklight-adapter-override-adapter-xml/)

To simplify: the adapter file gets deployed to the management server's database. From there server nodes get via the management service. The 'adapter' itself is then being run from the server's memory. It is transformed into an object in the server's memory.

Comment: Thank you Idan, the purpose of my question is that we want to implement the SSL to our adapter, which contains a password, however, this password can't be shared with the developers to coded it inside the xml file before the deployment. We thought after the deployment, we can change the password by finding the xml file again in the server database, but your answer says we can't since the adapter complied to and object only. Am I correct with this result.? thank you

Comment: Your assumption is correct. You cannot modify the adapter'x XML file post-deployment.

Comment: Thank you so much. Appreciate your response.