# IBM Worklight - Can I change invokeProcedure hostname and port?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server

I'm doing a demo application, and I need the app to be able to connect to different worklight servers. but I can't find where can I change the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to Worklight Adapters - you cannot change the adapter's connectivity properties during runtime. Explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17491703/5-0-6-changing-adapter-domain-and-port-configuration-after-deploy-through-conf), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15522613/how-to-pass-domain-port-number-username-and-password-from-user-input-to-workligh) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17015133/with-a-worklight-adapter-can-i-change-the-domain-and-port-for-a-procedure-at-run).

If you are referring to Worklight Server - I assume then that you are using Worklight 6.0; Right-click on the application folder >> Run As >> Build for Remote Server ([further explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17585522/ibm-worklight-how-to-connect-to-another-worklight-server-located-in-another-ma)).