# How to change IP and port on a Worklight App

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-8

How can i change the IP and port that my worklihgt 6.0.0 app has?
because ive deployed my app on the WAS server and the app  (desktop environmet) when tried to hit to server return this message:

```
The application failed connecting to the service.
```

i changed in the worklight.properties(in the WAS and in my worklight Project before compile): the publicWorkLightHostname - publicWorkLightProtocol - publicWorkLightPort to my WAS server, but the app stills hitting to my liberty local server.

where i can change this values?

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered before here: [IBM Worklight - How to connect to another Worklight Server located in another machine in the same network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17585522/ibm-worklight-how-to-connect-to-another-worklight-server-located-in-another-ma) Keep in mind that after you do Build for Remote Server, if you do Build All and Deploy again it will change it to your local Liberty Server; if you want to redeploy it, then do Build All and Deploy, then do Build for Remote Server and it will be pointing to the new server.