# Running Worklight Deployment Server with fixed IP to Generate War/Wlapp/.adapter files?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I am done with my Project and its time to Deploy things to the Websphere Server to host My Worklight Application based on Woklight 6.1.0.

Despite reading the following question, I still have a question.
[IBM Worklight - How to connect to another Worklight Server located in another machine in the same network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17585522/ibm-worklight-how-to-connect-to-another-worklight-server-located-in-another-ma/17586294#17586294)

The Websphere Server on which i have to Deploy my .war, .wlapp and .adapter files is remote server and does not fall under my company's domain. I do not have access to IP address and port provided by clients, So to deploy the same my backup plan is to copy files to a laptop having open network access and use RDP of the Window Server IP to deploy

My issues are:

1. As Worklight behaves, while i do Run as --> Run on Worklight Development Server it overwrite file properties like worklight.properties,.plist and index.html for windows with details of its local IP address.
2. When i do, Run --> Build Settings and Deploy Target I build the application to work with different Worklight Server and fill details i.e. Server: http: //182.19.xx.x0:9xx0 and Context Path: /Advisor. After doing it i see a message stating "Rebuild your Application after every change" then i click on 'OK'.

I expected it to rebuild everything for me as per details i provided but nothing happens. Is there anything i am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you add your remote server details in the Build Settings and Deploy Target window, *you are instructed* to re-build the application. Worklight Studio will not do this for you.

1. Change deployment target
2. Click OK
3. Right-click on the application folder and select Run As > Build All Environment

Per the [user documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_building_and_deploying_build_settings_deploy_target.html?lang=en):

> Important: This dialog is used only to specify configurations and
>   settings; clicking OK does not trigger a build. Any time that you make
>   a modification with this dialog, you must rebuild your application and
>   environments for your changes to take effect, using either the Run As
>   -> Run on Worklight Development Server or the Run As -> Build... menu commands.

Comment: Idan: Does "Change Deployment Target" means Clicking on Add server and to define a new server ?

Comment: No, it means ticking the checkbox "Build the application to work with a different Worklight server" and add the host and context, then building the application and taking the files for deployment in the external server.

Comment: Yeas Done. :). Idan last thing confirm. I have my SQL Adapter Modified with new IP Address provided by client. When i will deploy it to generate .adapter files. It will run on worklight development server. Will this cause any problem.

Comment: The adapter needs to be deployed to the same Worklight Server that the application will be connecting to.

Comment: Very Kool, I did generation of Adapter with my Local Worklight Server and will be deploying it on Actual Websphere Server.  So now i have everything in place expecting to finish project deployment today. Appreciate your efforts to Questions on worklight. :)